# Cross-language duplicates — doublons en langues différentes

Tags: discussion, language, exact-duplicates, close-reasons

Si deux questions sont des doublons au niveau du contenu, mais que l'une ainsi que ses réponses sont dans une langue (anglais ou français) tandis que l'autre question et ses réponses sont dans l'autre langue, faut-il clore l'une comme doublon de l'autre ?

---

If two questions are duplicates as far as the content is concerned, but one as well as its answers are in one language (French or English) whereas the other question and its answers are in the other language, should we close one as a duplicate of the other?

---

Exæmple: [Peut-on utiliser « ce » dans cette phrase ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/915/peut-on-utiliser-ce-dans-cette-phrase) & [What's the difference between "ce qui" and "ceux qui"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/whats-the-difference-between-ce-qui-and-ceux-qui)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oui, en les fusionnant autant que possible. Je ne vois aucune motivation pour conserver deux questions.

---

Yes, and try to merge the contents as much as possible. There is no point keeping two distinct questions.